# Second drop down depends on my first drop down. How?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a two drop downs in my program, and I want it to be like this:

- I have a list of employee and display/populate the list and put it
  inside of my   first drop down.
- Second is that, when I choose "Francis" the second drop down will
  have a value/event only for Francis and so on when I choose also another    employee.

I think the first drop down is correct, but I want to get the value of it and put it inside in my SQL statement in the WHERE clause in my second drop down. How?

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="cname">Client Name:</label></td>
        <td><select name="cname" id="cname">
            <option>Choose</option>
            <?php
                include("alqdb.php");
                $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ClientName FROM events");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<option>".$row["ClientName"]."</option>";
                    }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="survey">Survey:</label></td>
        <td><select name="survey" id="survey">
            <option>Choose</option>
            <?php
                include("alqdb.php");
                $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT EventTitle FROM events WHERE ClientName = 'Francis'");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<option>".$row["EventTitle"]."</option>";
                    }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: why are you including alqdb.php twice ??

Comment: there are 2 ways to do this 1 a simple get request, 2. a ajax request

Comment: It is for my database, I think I will get an error if I don't include the alqdb.php. Btw, can you show me some codes? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a ajax request for the second select:

create a php file for the ajax request
html:

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="cname">Client Name:</label></td>
        <td><select name="cname" id="cname">
            <option>Choose</option>
            <?php
                include("alqdb.php");
                $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ClientName FROM events");
                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                        echo "<option>".$row["ClientName"]."</option>";
                    }
            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="survey">Survey:</label></td>
        <td><select name="survey" id="survey">
            <option>Choose</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

ajax.php

```
 <?php
     include("alqdb.php");
     $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT EventTitle FROM events WHERE ClientName = '"$_GET['cname']"'");
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         echo "<option>".$row["EventTitle"]."</option>";
     }
 ?>
```

js:

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('#cname').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
     url:ajax.php,
     data:{cname:$('#cname').val()};
     type:'get',
     contentType:'html',
     success:function(data){
     $('#survey').append(data);
    }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Madalin, but it is not working. I delete the second drop down php code and do what you said. I create a php file with the code you gave to me. How about the js file? I put it in the <script> tag inside the alqbilling.php (name of the file) of the code I've posted. :)

Comment: It's ok Madalin, I really appreciate your effort in helping me. Haha. :) It is ok to use POST?

Comment: yes change the type to post and use $_POST in ajax.php

Comment: Slr Madalin, but it is not working. :( I tried your method but when I choose Francis, the second drop down will not show anything. I want to show the event when that event reserved by Francis and so on. :)

Comment: does the xhr request take place on select change?

Comment: what do you mean? I think the ajax.php file is not connected to my alqbilling.php. do I need to call it?

Comment: haha. nvm about that. :) can you check your code? if there is something wrong?

Comment: ohh. sorry2. when I create the ajax.php all I need is to create a new file? and also the <script>, I will put it inside in the alqbilling.php. it is correct? :)

Comment: damn man you are killing me, you put the jquery with the html in a file

Comment: sorry2. it is inside in the ajax.php?

Comment: I put the jquery inside the <script> tag and below the </body> tag. I'm still new in jquery though. :)

Comment: not in the ajax.php in the page with the selects and not ouside the body tag,inside

Comment: I really sorry Madalin. thank you for helping me. but still, it is not working. :( there is also no error in your code. but the second drop down will not show anything when I choose Francis or other client name. :(